# Can lodash remove arrays containing only null or undefined?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a data object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    "one":      null,
    "two":      undefined,
    "three":    [undefined],
    "four":     "valid value"
}
```

And I need to end up with this:

```
{
    "four":     "valid value"
}
```

I'm using lodash to try and accomplish this, and it's gotten me part way there:

```
obj = _.pick(obj, _identity);
```

Which gives me:

```
{
    "three":    [undefined],
    "four":     "valid value"
}
```

Is there a lodash-centric way to also remove not only keys whose values are null or undefined and also remove keys whose values are arrays that contain only undefined or null? I know there's a bunch of ways to do this in general, I was just wondering if lodash had some way to do this baked in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `_.omitBy()` with `_.empty()` for objects (including arrays), and `!value` for primitives. You should also `_.compact()` arrays before checking if they're empty to ignore `falsy` values:

```js
var obj = {
    "one":      null,
    "two":      undefined,
    "three":    [undefined],
    "four":     "valid value",
}

var fn = o => _.omitBy(o, v => _.isObject(v) ? 
  _.isEmpty(_.isArray(v) ? _.compact(v) : v)
  : 
  !v
)

var result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you to remove `falsy` values and empty arrays/objects in a nested object/array, use `_.transform()` recursively. Use `_.compact()` to remove `falsy` values from arrays, and `_.isEmpty()` and `Boolean` to check:

If you need a recursive solution you can use `_.transform()`:

```js
var obj = {
    "one":      null,
    "two":      undefined,
    "three":    [undefined],
    "four":     "valid value",
    "five":     [undefined, 1],
    "six":      [{ a: null, b: [] }, undefined]
}

var cleanArray = (o) => _.isArray(o) ? _.compact(o) : o;

var clean = o => _.transform(o, (r, v, k) => {
  var isObject = _.isObject(v)
  var val = isObject ? cleanArray(clean(v)) : v
  var keep = isObject ? !_.isEmpty(val) : Boolean(val)
  
  if(keep) r[k] = val
})

var result = clean(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user633183 - no worries. I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

use without

> Creates an array excluding all given values using SameValueZero for
>   equality comparisons.

https://lodash.com/docs/#without

```
obj = _.without(obj, undefined,null,[undefined])
```

Comment: `_.without(obj, undefined,null,[undefined])` will return an empty array for `obj = {"one":      null,
    "two":      undefined,
    "three":    [undefined],
    "four":     "valid value"}`